# Beginner Python: Calculation Formatting

Tags: python, format

I am working on an assignment and have run into a roadblock. Attached is my code. The purpose of this code is to develop a bmi table given the users inputs of beginning weight, end weight, beginning height, and end height. I have also attached the BMI calculator that will process the BMI given the weight and height. The BMI calculator will convert height (in inches) to meters, and weight (in pounds) to KG. So far my code prints out the weight across and the height vertically. The question is, how do I fill the inside with the appropriate BMI?

```
def calculateBMI(height, weight):
    # This will process the parameters above and convert to 
    # meters and pounds accordingly.
    heightMeter = height * 0.0254

    # This will process weight into KG where 1 pound = .4536 KG
    weightKG = weight * 0.4536

    # Given the new converted numbers, this will then 
    # calculate BMI and return the output.
    calcBMI = (weightKG) / (heightMeter * heightMeter)
    return calcBMI

def printBMITable(startHeight, endHeight, startWeight, endWeight):
    for x in range (startWeight, endWeight + 1, 10):
        print "\t",x,
    print
    print

    for i in range(startHeight, endHeight + 1):
        print i
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using `rjust` and a nested for-loop? The `rjust` method of the built-in type `str` can help you adjust to tabs. For example, on my terminal, tabs count as 8 spaces. And the print comma operator automatically prints an extra space. Thus I used `rjust(8-1)` or `rjust(7)` in the following code and it printed very nicely on my terminal:

```
def printBMITable(startHeight, endHeight, startWeight, endWeight):

    for x in range (startWeight, endWeight + 1, 10):
        print "\t",x,

    print '\n'

    for i in range(startHeight, endHeight + 1):
        print i,
        for x in range(startWeight, endWeight + 1, 10):
            print str(round(calculateBMI(i, x), 2)).rjust(7),
        print ''
```

Output:

```
>>> printBMITable(195, 200, 190, 200)
        190     200

195    3.51     3.7
196    3.48    3.66
197    3.44    3.62
198    3.41    3.59
199    3.37    3.55
200    3.34    3.52
```

Note that I also used the built-in `round` function to shorten the number of decimal places when printing the BMI. You can feel free to avoid that however or change your precision to whatever number of decimal places you desire.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a nested loop, basically something like:

```
for weight in range(startWeight, endWeight):
    for height in range(startHeight, endHeight):
         #calculate BMI and print
```